# feature importance in neural network (classification problem)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction, feature-selection

i have a classification problem and i need to find important features.
my code as follow:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.99, input_dim=len(X_train.columns)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu',name='layer1'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='layer'))
print(model.summary())

# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model=model.fit(X_train, y_train,validation_data = (X_val, y_val), epochs=100, batch_size=1,)
```

how can i find important features? as you can see in the code it is not a regression problem.